# Opencart payment extension install

Tags: php, opencart, codeigniter-3, opencart-3

I am installed bank transfer extension in opencart 3x. but catalog side error does not show payment method.

Error will be also here

```
undefined index error
```

Comment: Please show the code that produces this error.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You change zone to `admin -> extension -> payment -> Bank transfer`

After select All Zone

if **all zone** not selected. your bank transfer wil be work on limited country.

[image: Click Here See Screenshot]